# How much of Thor is based on actual mythology?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, comic-adaptation, thor

Not having read the comics at all and not being a huge mythology buff, I have only the general knowledge of some Norse mythology and Thor's (comic/movie version) background.

Obviously the names and some settings are the same. But what I'm referring to is the general setting (Asgard, the bifrost, etc), the character's personality (Loki is known as a trickster God if my recollection serves properly) and countless other examples (Mjolnir, Odinsleep, Frost Giants, etc).

How much of the Thor universe is based off of *actual* Norse mythology and how much of it is either created from the comic for the movie and so on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I'll attempt an answer, based only on the movie (not the comics) and my small bit of knowledge about Norse mythology (paired with up-to-date Wiki-research).

First of all the movie depicts the gods as being just a kind of powerful aliens (wandering on the same paths as *Stargate* and its farther-in-spirit *Erich von Däniken* already did). Indeed this isn't that bad an idea, as in Norse mythology (like in Greek mythology and I guess many other pantheistic religions) the gods aren't that almighty as the monotheistic gods. They can be killed by other gods, fight with each other, and aren't completely all-knowing by birth (I think Odin had to sacrifice his eye for gaining the power to see the future). They didn't even create the world on their own, I think. So they are indeed just another race of very powerful, maybe even immortal, but not allmighty, beings in the mythology.

Then *Odin* is indeed the highest of the *Aesir*, the higher of the two god races, so it makes sense for him to be the king of *Asgard* (the home of the *Aesir*) in the movie. Furthermore he is the father of *Thor*. But as said, he doesn't lose his eye in a battle against giants, as depicted in the movie, but sacrifices it in order to gain future-seeing powers.

But in mythology everybody knows *Loki* is the son of two giants (one of them being *Laufey*, as mentioned in the movie) and nobody would think he is *Odin*'s son. But even in mythology he is still counted to the *Aesir* and not to the giants, and is indeed somehow like a brother to *Thor*, with them getting into many adventures together (but also fighting each other when *Thor* is fed up with *Loki*'s tricks). In mythology he is a very ambivalent character, too. He is both intelligent and intrigant and often helps the other gods with his cunning, while other times trying to sabotage them and even fighting on the side of the giants and other monsters in the final apocalyptic battle. But he doesn't offensively try to kill all humans or even fight the other gods directly, as in the movie, though he would be best choice if the movie wants an intelligent and powerful enemy for *Thor*.

---

**EDIT:** It seems he is even banned from *Asgard* by *Odin* after he has gone too far with one of his intrigues and is actually the leader of the giants during *Ragnarok* (the final battle). This might be seen as parallel to the movie.

---

*Thor* is depicted not that inaccurately, I think, being very powerful and sometimes a bit carefree. He does more count on strength than on intelligence or tactics, but he's not dumb. But I think they made him a bit more likeable/friendly in the movie (/comic?) to better appeal to the audience. He also wields the hammer *Mjölnir* in mythology (though I'm not sure it has to be a hammer in all sources), whose feature to always return to *Thor* was also depicted in the movie. But he doesn't really have such a gang of co-fighters and friends as in the movie and I don't know in which way they are based on "real" gods (though one of them is called *Sif*, which is the name of *Thor*'s wife).

The movie depicts the world *Jötunheim* to be the home of the *Frost Giants*, although they are actually from *Niflheim* (but this is just a minor deviation, as *Jötunheim* is the home of the *Giants*). But the giants and frost giants are indeed the main antagonists of the gods and *Thor* would often venture into their lands to beat them up, sometimes together with *Loki*.

The *Bifröst* is actually the rainbow bridge between *Midgard* and *Asgard* and is indeed guarded by *Heimdall*, so it makes sense, in the context of the movie, to turn it into some hyperspace teleporter or something the like. But it does just connect *Midgard* (say Earth) to *Asgard* and doesn't connect all the 9 worlds together, I think, as depicted in the movie (maybe they have to go over *Midgard* to reach the other worlds in the mythology?).

And this whole *Destroyer* thing (this guarding robot misused by *Loki*) is utter crap. And I think also this urn the giants want to steal doesn't have any real background.

---

**EDIT:** Regarding the Odinsleep from the comics, I don't think this has any real background. When in real life you say "someone is going to Odinsleep" means he is entering a very deep and long sleep. This goes back to a particular legend as part of the *Sigurd*-legend (I'm not sure how far this applies to the more modern and mythology-cleaned *Nibelung*-legend), where *Odin* made *Brynhild* sink into a very long sleep for doing something wrong (I think for killing or rather choosing the wrong men in her role as *Valkyrie*, at least in the versions where she is a *Valkyrie*). But I don't think there is any mythological instance of Odin himself going into a long and vulnerable sleep.

---

These were just some small and superficial things I could come up with. All in all I think they did quite a good job to transfer all those mythological things into some kind of "super-powerful aliens"-context and treated the mythological sources not that inaccurately, even if making some errors and creating some things anew (Ok, this robot destroyer thing was really rubbish). But besides that I was indeed surpised how they managed to turn a god into a superhero without hurting *Norse* mythology that badly (though an expert on the topic may think differently).

Comment: If I recall correctly , Loki does cause Ragnorok to occur.

Comment: @DForck42 Not sure, but he seems to be the leader of the bad guys during Ragnarok.

Comment: Interesting that Odinsleep isn't from mythology, I could swear I saw that in another modern adaptation of Norse myth (maybe [Gargoyles?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargoyles_%28TV_series%29)).

Comment: @Keen Well, it seems he can send people to such a long sleep and maybe he has done it more often then just in this particular event in the *Sigurd*-legend. But it just doesn't seem to go back to himself sleeping for a long time.

Comment: +1 for a great answer. However, Thor in Norse religion was an unintelligent brute. In the movies (at least in The Avengers), he is depicted as well spoken and at least somewhat intelligent.

Comment: @DustinDavis Yeah, might be true. Yet they didn't completely drop his careless and bragging aspects, especially at the beginning, until he learned some more modesty during the movie.

Comment: I'm currently rereading Douglas Adams' "The Long Dark Teatime if the Soul", and while is does not include the word "Odinsleep" it goes on about rather extensively how sleeping is Odins preferred occupation. No idea if that is in any way related to a pre-existing idea of Odin, but since I stumbled upon it I thought I mention it.

Comment: I believe 'Odinsleep' is from the comic book series.

Answer (score 1):

In the mythology, Loki is blood brother of Odin.  He is a Giant, not an Aesir, and its common knowledge.  He is a trickster and a shapeshifter, and fathered and mothered Hel, goddess of the underworld; Fenris, the giant wolf destined to kill Odin at Ragnarok; and Jormungand, the serpent that wraps the earth biting its tail.  He ends up chained beneath the earth for orchestrating the death of Odin's son Baldur.

Thor is not destined to be king.  He's destined to be killed at the same time as his father Odin, at Ragnarok, by Jormungand.  He's a brawler and a boozer, a boaster and unable to resist a challenge, and he gets in trouble because of it frequently.  He marries Sif and their two sons survive Ragnarok.

Odin is the All-father, god of War, death, wisdom and poetry.  He sacrificed himself to himself by impailing himself to hang upside down from the world tree, staring into the well of knowledge, discovering the runes from which the alphabet is based.  He likes to wander the earth disguised as an old beggar and test men's hospitality, bringing doom on you if it was found lacking.  He was also rather devious and not altogether to be trusted if you weren't Aesir.

The movies and comic books do a pretty terrible job of representing Norse mythology.  About the only bit they got right was that Thor has a hammer no one can lift.  Which was made for him by dwarves, and had nothing to do with Excalibur whatsoever.

Comment: "Do a pretty terrible job" has the assumption that they're *trying* to represent Norse mythology, when in fact, they're trying to create their own story (with Norse gods being technologically advanced aliens) that's *inspired* by Norse mythology.

Comment: Moreover, the films aren't even adapted directly from the myths; they're inspired by a line of comic books which themselves have a very tenuous connection to the actual myths.